# Can Xbox One codes for Fifa 14 (Day One edition) be redeemed worldwide?

Tags: region-lock, xbox-one, fifa-14, digital-distribution

Mirosoft announced a while ago that games on the Xbox One would not be region locked. However, some DLC might be. As the system is not quite clear on what is possible and what not, I am doubting myself when it comes to codes for digital content. The European version of the Xbox One Day One Edition came with a download code for FIFA 14 and a Day One Pack unlocking some in game content.

Would this content be available abroad with the European code? Would the game be downloadable for sure but the DLC maybe not?

Comment: Since this usually is different from game to game and certainly from publisher to publisher, I think this question is not really answerable nor a good fit since it solicits speculation and opinion. It is also too broad, which I used to flag it.

Comment: Asking the question about all Xbox One codes in general is too broad. If you focus the question to the FIFA 14 DLC, it should be scoped well enough.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will rescope the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully transferred my European (German) code to a chap in the UK. He was able to redeem and download both the game and the Day One Launch pack. While it does not give any insight to code trading across PAL/NTSC territories, it provides some insight.